# Google Analytics Query explorer returning data for custom dimension but not able to get data via API call using RGoogleAnalyticsRGoogleAnalytics

Tags: r, google-analytics

If I remove the custom dimensions 15 and 16 the code runs perfectly fine but does not return anything with them.

I checked the query with query explorer and it returns the data perfectly fine.

```
    query.list <- Init(start.date = "2017-02-01",
               end.date = "2017-02-04",
               dimensions = "ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel,ga:pagePath,ga:dimension15,ga:dimension16",
               #dimensions = paste(toString(paste("ga:dimension", dim, sep="")),"ga:pagePath,ga:eventLabel,ga:eventAction",sep=", "),
               metrics = "ga:totalEvents",
               max.results = 10000,
    #                   table.id = "ga:XXXXXX"
               table.id = "ga:XXXXX"
               )


    ga.query <- QueryBuilder(query.list)


    ga.data <- GetReportData(ga.query, token, split_daywise = T)
```

Comment: Have you defined your customDimension15 & 16 before making a request ?  Check this article https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

Comment: Yes, I have defined the custom dimensions 15 and 16, as I get their data when I run through the query explorer. Issue arises when I try to access these dimensions via r API

Comment: How are you authenticating your `RGoogleAnalytics` application. If it is a service account you need to add the the service account to the particular account. The RGoogleAnalytics and the query explorer use the same API under the hood so there is likely some difference in how you are constructing the request.

Comment: I got it. I was passing different dates. The dates that I was trying in the API call, that time the dimensions were not created. Now with the new dates it work perfectly fine. Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dates that I was passing the team did not create those custom dimensions during that time.